# add only certain rules for sonar scanner instead of excluding

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Instead of excluding or ignore rules in sonar's property file, I'd like to have only a few certain rules for sonar to analyse, so I don't need to exclude a large number of rules out of 344 rules for c++. How can I do that? (I'm not adding customized rules)

I imageine the syntax would be:   (in *.properties* file)

```
sonar.issue.include.multicriteria=***
sonar.issue.include.multicriteria.***.ruleKey=cpp:S984
....
```

EDIT:

1, I need to configure this in a CLI environment.
2, It's about one project, two rule sets. one rule sets for local use and the other one for CI/CD use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to craft a [Quality Profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles) that contains only your rules of interest, and then either make it the default profile for C++, or explicitly assign your project to it.

BTW, correctly setting exclusions in properties (versus through the UI) is quite tricky. I'm not sure about the correctness of the `ruleKey` field name, and you're probably missing another field in there, but your syntax seems to be on the right track.

Comment: That seems working but I probably need it to be a CLI tool. Also, my situation here is there's only one project, but 2 rule sets -- one for local use and the other one for CI/CD use.

Comment: The only variant of that that's currently supported @Henry is the default rule set for local use (SonarLint in unconnected mode) and a custom rule set on the server.